# Relative References in Excel 2011 Mac for Dynamic Report Macros (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, csv

**Input:**

Text File (CSV) from Apple Remote Desktop on Application Usage for a dynamic series of Macs.

**Goal:**

To convert the CSV File from Apple Remote Desktop into an easy-to-read format using a series of Excel Macros (or other options as possible). This will be used among numerous teams, so the amount of data will always be changing in every report.

**Methodology So Far:**

I'm doing this in a series of small macros, primarily to make it easier to troubleshoot. The primary issue is the way ARD records Application Usage: every instance of an application starting and shutting down and the length of time it was running is in a separate row. In this row there are two kinds of time: "Front Most" and "Front Most in Seconds."

"Front Most" is recorded in this format: "1h, 5m" making it impossible to use for any sort of total.
"Front Most in Seconds" is recorded as a standard number and is the focus of this project.

**Macros:**

Here are the macros I've successfully built without issue:

*Macro 1*: ARD_Convert1_Import - Import text file from predetermined location into a new sheet in an existing workbook. This contains just the basic conversion from CSV to Excel.

*Macro 2*: ARD_Convert2_Columns - Makes some minor adjustments to the columns, including adding columns to allow for the calculation of seconds into hours, along with removing the unnecessary columns in the report. (Note: the columns are always the same in every worksheet. It's the rows that change.)

*Macro 3a*: ARD_Convert3_TableSelect - This is supposed to select the entire table dynamically, which it does perfectly.

```
Sub ARD_Convert3_TableSelect()
    Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
End Sub
```

***Macro 3b***: ARD_Convert3_WholeTable - This is my problem point. I need to convert the selected information in "3a" into a table. However, even with "Relative References" selected, when I record the macro, it always has absolute references built in.

Example:

```
Sub ARD_Convert3_WholeTable()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$J$284"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table3"
    ActiveCell.Range("Table3[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
End Sub
```

My biggest problem with this is that absolute references keep sneaking into my code and I cannot figure out how to make them relative references. I've tried to create dynamic named ranges to use in the Range("$A$1:$J$284") field. I've tried a dozen different ideas and have come up totally empty.

This is the LAST piece I need for this.

Please help!

-rks

Comment: Is the problem that you have a static reference (e.g. from A1 to J284 inclusive) recorded into the macro instead of a dynamic reference (e.g. whatever the current selection is)? I don't see any real difference between absolute ($A$1:$J$284) and relative (A1:J284) references in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging your 2 macros:

```
Sub ARD_Convert3_WholeTable()
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
                     ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes)

        .Name = "Table3"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough! This is exactly what I needed. I knew there was just some command I didn't know.